# Entity Framework 4 - Persisting Child Objects using only foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, orm

I have a many to many relationship in my EF4 model (many groups can have many programs).

I have a set of program Id's and a group. I want my group to have the programs that are represented by the program Id's that I have.

What I don't want to do is go to the database to get the program entities. I already know their Id's.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a trick with dummy classes:

```
// you have a group
var group = GetGroupSomehow();
// if group is unknown to the context Attach it
context.Groups.Attach(group); // if it is a new group use AddObject
// now add programs
foreach(var program in programId.Select(id => new Program { Id = id }))
{
    // Attach dummy program first
    context.Programs.Attach(program);
    // Now make relation between group and program
    group.Programs.Add(program);
} 

context.SaveChanges();
```

The only requirement is that none `Program` from programIds is already loaded. If any program is loaded it will be more complicated because you will first have to check it in `ObjectStateManager` and use loaded instance.